# CTE Recursive Queries in Doctrine 2.5

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a table Users that has 2 key columns of referrer and referral_code which is a simple implementation of a tree structure. target is to get a trail of users based on who referred them to use this application.

```
NAME       |     Referrer     | Referral_Code
----------------------------------------------
Super User |     000          |  001
User A     |     001          |  002         
User B     |     002          |  003
User C     |     003          |  004
User n     |     00n          |  00n-1
```

I need a recursive query where based on a trigger e.g a report of `User C` activities can yield a trace string on referrers to a depth of 4 maximum. 
My desired output string is `004-003-002-001` which implies the trace of referrals based on the users activity. The tree can grow infinitely in depth so a trace of say `User QA` can yield a stack trace of the 4 people up the tree joined on the referral codes.
I'm using `doctrine 2.5` as the `ORM`.
Constraints

1. A user must be referred to use the system
2. A user can refer multiple users to use the system

Comment: AFAIK CTEs aren't supported. You need to skipp DQL and use "Native queries", or use pain SQL over db connection. Either way, you need to look for Common Table Expression in your db docs or if unsupported, you need their equvalent.

Answer (score 0):

Somnambulist.tech built a common table expression (CTE) Doctrine expression builder that is wrapper for aliasing the clauses that will reside within the WITH clause.

https://github.com/somnambulist-tech/cte-builder

Simple example:

```php
$eb = new ExpressionBuilder($connection);
$eb->createExpression('tacos');
$eb->tacos->select('id', 'type')->from('tacos'); // or $eb->get('tacos');
$eb->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

If the depths of 4 is fixed, you don't need recursion, just a self join 4 times.
If you really want to use recursion, you can write your own DQL Function for your dbms. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

Comment: SQL supports recursion through syntax of CTEs. Custom functions are not enough. If there is a way to add custom syntax though...